# How do I get "user locale names folders"

Tags: bash, scripts, locale

I`m writing a script to config a shared zfs partition, independent of which OS distro I decide to boot; To do so I have to store then locale Names of current User who runs the script, which depends of the language I mean "~/Documents" for English or "~/Documentos" for Spanish ...
I found difficult automatic this simple issue in my script.

Any suggestion are welcome
thanks

PD: the only steep that I make it was, get the actual locale from this file

cat ~/.config/user-dirs.locale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you look for:

```
xdg-user-dir DOCUMENTS
```

See `man xdg-user-dir`.

Comment: Many THANK`s You have right ...
.. I have try this commnd "man xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update" without result,
 I did not know about THAT command.
Thanks again it was quick, And I like it.